# Primefaces menu onhide event

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, show-hide

I have a menu with a trigger on a button click event. 
On the client side whenever the menu is visible i would like to add some style to trigger button and when menu is hidden remove the style from button.

For adding the style i can add a listener to the button and add style.
But when the menu is hidden how can i add a listener to menu so that i can remove the style from the button?

Is there a way to add a listener to the menu component hide event

Below is the code-snippet for the menu and button for references:

```
<div class="round-button-circle">
                        <p:link id="MenuLink" href="javascript:void(0)"/>
                    </div>
                <p:menu overlay="true" widgetVar="menuWidgetVar" trigger="MenuLink" styleClass="PageHeaderMenu ui-menu-child" >
                    <p:menuitem ...
                </p:menu>
```

Comment: look at the PrimeFaces javascript source of the menu component. This source is easily readable and extendable/overridable.Or maybe you see some event there that you can hook into.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it by overriding the hide function on the menu widgetVar instance.
Somehow the widgetVar was not initialized in the document.ready event hence i had to lazy initialize the menu-

Added a onclick listener for the button

```
<p:link id="MenuLink" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showUserMenu();"/>
```

Below is the code for the onclick listener:

```
var showUserMenu = function() {
var menuWidget = PF('menuWidgetVar');
if(menuWidget === undefined) {
    return;
}

//lazy initialzed because the PF widgetVar is not visible in document.ready event
if(!menuSettings.initialized) {
    //proxy the method for hide to update styles
    var _hide = menuWidget.hide;
    menuWidget.hide = function() {
        _hide.apply(menuWidget);

        //on hide remove style classes
        $("#MenuLink").removeClass('button-selected');

    };
    menuSettings.initialized = true;
}

//on click add style classes
$("#MenuLink").addClass('button-selected');
};
```